# Java client/server architecture

Tags: java, client-server

I have some experience using JAVA EE 6 along with frameworks like Seam, I've used glassfish and Jboss AS. I want to develop a couple of games now and they have a client/server architecture, but using an application server seems like an overkill as each party must set up their server to play, so I thought about going with plain Java SE. I've read about grizzly and nio.

My problem is, I've only found examples on how to implement this in a very simple case. Or they seemed unnecessarily complex. I was thinking about using MVC with observer so I have a clean separation between the game logic and the views, along with remote proxies to simulate that the other players are playing locally, so I don't need to duplicate logic if I ever want to add AI players.

Can you point me in the right direction? Is that a good idea? Resources on this? I understand the are a lot but I'm looking for best practices or a fancy approach on solving this.

Comment: sorry but the requirements of your application and the architecture that you already have in mind are too fuzzy for anyone to give you useful feedback. what exactly are your particular requirements? why can't you do socket connections?

Comment: I never said I couldn't do sockets. I simply explained how I was thinking it'd like to abstract their use for upper layers, but the underlying implementation for the server and client to communicate could be implemented through sockets.

Comment: I didn't mean that I assumed that you couldn't use sockets in particular, it was just an example of a possible solution that I couldn't analyze because I didn't know enough about your problem. Try providing more info, it is an interesting problem and you will surely get good input

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, The simplest way to distribute game data is to use JMS Topics. This will ensure the same messages are distributed across your system. (And it will take care of the sockets)

I would use [ActiveQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) because its easy to get started, however [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) is a very fast free server.

This will allow you to distribute your application how you like.